# SherlockActionbar with Two Fragments inside of it

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I'm a bit confused. Basically I have **two fragments**. And **one single SherlockFragmentActivity** as their container. It can be accessed via Tab-Tab.

Each Fragments have each own XML (layout containing buttons, textview, etc).

Usually before I use actionbar, I put the declaration of each components (button, etc, listener, etc) inside the Main Activity (its container).

**My question is,**

Based on my first case above. 
Where should i put the declaration of components manipulation?
Is it inside the method of **onCreateView()** on each Fragments 
or should I put it only inside of **onCreate()** on the main Container ? -SherlockFragmentActivity

**And is it dangerous?**

please share a bit of guidance. thx

Answer (score 0):

in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); //if you need it
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //here you do your "components manipulation"
    // call getView().findViewById(...) for getting components
}
```